# Powershell: Setting anonymous user in IIS6

Tags: iis-6, scripting, identity, powershell-2.0

I'm using the PowerShell script below to set anonymous user identity and authentication methods on an IIS6 server. The script seems to work at first, but if I issue an iisreset after running it the values revert to the old ones! How do I persist them?

```
 $server = "localhost"
 $siteName = "www.mysite.com"
 $iis = [ADSI]"IIS://$server/W3SVC"
 $site = $iis.children | where { $_.keyType -eq "IIsWebServer" -and $_.ServerComment -eq $siteName }
 $path = [ADSI]($site.path+"/ROOT")
 $path.AnonymousUserName = "user"
 $path.AnonymousUserPass = "pass"
 $path.AuthFlags = 3
 $path.CommitChanges()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the metabase is not persisted at once. iisreset forces shutdown of the IIS services and the information is lost.

There are two ways of fixing this:

1. Run `C:\WINDOWS\system32\IIsCnfg.vbs /save`
2. `net stop` and then `net start`